# Should I be using a ForeignKey in this Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I've been reading a lot about Django and have finally begun developing the models for a project I've outlined, but I'm having trouble understanding ForeignKeys, and how/when to use them. I have read a bit about database work to better understand Foreign keys in general, but with no prior database experience I am still kind of confused.

I've come up with an example situation, similar to the project I'm working on and would like to know if both uses of the ForeignKey are proper, or should I use a OneToOneField or ManyToManyField in their place.

In this example situation, I would like each Bridge to have multiple builders, and each tool to have multiple different users (or Builders who are skilled with them). I would NOT like a builder to work on multiple bridges at the same time (OneToOne??). However, I would like each builder to have the ability to have multiple Tools they are skilled with(ManyToMany??).

```
    class Builder(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField( max_length = 50 )

    class Bridge(models.Model):
        bridge_name = models.CharField( max_length = 50 )
        builders = models.ForeignKey(Builder)

    class Tool(models.Model):
        tool_name = models.CharField( max_length = 50 )
        users = models.ForeignKey( Builder )
```

From my understanding, I can retrieve all of a builders' tools in the views.py file, although I haven't gotten to this part of the development yet, and would like to ensure I have a strong model before getting that far.

Considering how generic and open-ended this question can be, overall I would just like someone to explain:

```
WHY each ForeignKey relationship in this example 
model is either used correctly or incorrectly.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not actually a Django question but rather a ORM question, you need to understand what and how ORM works (apart from the language and the framework used).
Your case yields different results:

1 Bridge can Have Many workers (One (bridge) <--* Many (Worker), ForeignKey)

1 Bridge can have 1 worker (One (Bridge) <--> One (Worker), One To One field)

Many Bridges can have many workers (Many (Bridges) * -- * many (Workers), Many to Many field)

If you use a ForeignKey from tools to builders, it means that a worker can have many tools, but each tool is unique to a worker, if you have many to many then any worker can have any tool. 
If you need tools to belong to many different workers, then you need a many to many relation, if the tools need some specific restrictions (like skills) then again a many to many relation with specific limitations (a through table could hold extra information regarding the association, like worker 1 uses tool 1 every friday, that would be a through table of workers to tools with the middle table holding the day the worker uses the specific tool).

Comment: If you specify the foreignkey in the bridge, then you are actually telling that a bridge belongs to a worker, and a worker can have many different bridges, if you specify the foreignkey in the worker, then it means that a worker has a bridge, but a bridge can have many workers. Imagine it as a dropdown, if you add the relation in the worker model then you choose for the specific worker the bridge (in a dropdown), if you specify it the other way around, you select the worker for a bridge.